# Kendo UI + Web Components

Tags: kendo-ui, polymer

Since I had problems, with a simple test, I went back to the original Telerik page that shows the integration of the kendo components in a polymer application
It looks like ANY example (it's easy, since there is a Dojo link...) doesn't work, at least with the current version of Kendo.
What am I missing???
Andrea
P.S.: the page is this one: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/webcomponents

**Update**:

I can obtain the behavior of the kendo grid, for example, with the following approach:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<script src="../telerik/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="../telerik/js/kendo.webcomponents.js"></script>

<dom-module id="my-view2">

  <link rel="import" type="css" href="../telerik/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="import" type="css" href="../telerik/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="import" type="css" href="../telerik/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css">

  <template>

    <style include="shared-styles">
       :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    ...

  <div id="grid"></div>
  ...


  ready: function () {
    var element = $(this.$.grid).kendoGrid({
      dataSource: [
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Pamela Andersson' },
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Naomi Campbell' },
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Monica Bellucci' }
      ],
      sortable: true,
      filterable: true,
      selectable: true
    });
  }
```

But I cannot obtain the styles correctly applied. Even if the official documentation says that it's deprecated, it should still work, including the external stylesheets as you can see in the code (any other 'position' breaks the code...).
So for example sorting works, but I cannot see the correct icon.
When I try to filter, the form appears unstyled, and in the topleft corner of the window...

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your symptoms following the first steps of the [Telerik guide](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/webcomponents#include-scripts). The console indicates that the Kendo-specific Web Components script is not found on the server:

[image: screenshot]

While the `webcomponentsjs` polyfill shouldn't be needed for Chrome, there may be modifications in their version of the polyfill that are needed for Kendo UI to function properly.

I recommend submitting a support request with the Kendo team.

Comment: You can bypass this problem referencing the non-minified version (kendo.webcomponents.js, I found it downloading the trial version locally), but the result are still wrong (the drop-down of a combo opens up in the top-left part of the page, and not under the component, styles are totally lost, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I've published webcomponent wrappers for Kendo UI Core at [Kendoui-core-components](https://github.com/arthwang/kendoui-core-components) that make Kendo UI (for jQuery) can be initialized through html element attributes, like:

```
<k-auto-complete id="customers"
                       data-text-field="ContactName"
                       data-source='{
                         type:"odata",
                         transport:{
                           read:"https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"},
                           group:{field:"Country"}
                          }'
                       heigth="400"
                       style="width:100%"></k-auto-complete>
```

You can install the package by 'npm i kendoui-core-components'.
Meanwhile I also authored a VSCode extension called 'vsc-kendo-core-components' which provides autocomplete for editing element attributes.
Hope the two derivatives make Kendo UI for jQuery more intuitive and effective.

Comment: Linking to outside sources makes for a bad answer because if the link becomes dead in the future the answer no longer will be helpful. Would be useful to add as much as you can into the answer itself.

Comment: I think that’s unfair. @chevybow. The external link here is to a library which the answer is proposing the questioner use instead of directly using the Kendo documented approach for instantiation of custom-elements. I think that’s reasonable and, having had painful experience of Kendo UI + WebComponents I think the wrapper is a good answer and one I’m grateful to have learned from.